# How to Write Loop in iMacros

Tags: loops, imacros

I have the following code which needs to be rewritten for 10 times in order to satisfy my work. For example if my code is

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-email CONTENT=myemail1@mymail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out

URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-email CONTENT=myemail2@mymail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out

URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-email CONTENT=myemail3@mymail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out

URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-email CONTENT=myemail4@mymail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out

URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-email CONTENT=myemail5@mymail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out
```

In the above most of the code is static and all I need is to change the email as `myemail1@mymail.com` and `myemail2@mymail.com` etc so on... so there anyway I can write a loop so that it automatically changes the email on loop for 10 times with 10 different emails to play the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

run with loop

```
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-email CONTENT=myemail{{!loop}}@mymail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>In
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out
```